# Operator with compact resolvent

Tags: spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $T$ be a closed unbounded operator with compact resolvent, this means that there exists $\lambda_0 \in \rho(T)$ such that $(T- \lambda_0)^{-1}$ is compact.

Is it true that $\forall \lambda \in \rho(T)$we have $(T- \lambda)^{-1}$ is compact??

Comment: Yes. To prove this, use the "resolvent identities": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism#Resolvent_identity

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I didn’t reached the compactness, can you help me to rearrange the identity to obtain the result?

Comment: Remember that the sum of compact operators is compact and that the product of a bounded operator with a compact one is compact. Using the first resolvent identity, write the resolvent at $\lambda$ as the sum of two compact operators.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank u